# I want this to be checked over and over again during android until it equals on android

Tags: java, android

```
    public void time() {

        Calendar c_enter = Calendar.getInstance();
        c_enter.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 0);
        c_enter.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c_enter.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c_enter.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c_enter.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        Calendar c_expected = Calendar.getInstance();
        c_expected.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 0);
        c_expected.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        c_expected.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c_expected.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        c_expected.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        c_expected.getTime();
        c_enter.getTime();

        while (!c_enter.equals(c_expected)) {
            if (c_enter.equals(c_expected)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Incorrect version. Please update.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't toast in the activity when 30 seconds has passed. Be gentle, android while noobie.

on Android.

Comment: Besides everything else that's wrong with this approach, you do realize that you aren't updating the values of c_enter and/or c_expected within your while loop?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? YOu make 2 `Calendar` objects with -i think- the same date / time. Then you get the time (which shoudl be equal, right?). Then you do a while they are not equal (so the only time you are "in" the while, is when they are not equal) where you start to ask an 'if' for them to be equal, which ofcourse will never happen.

Answer (score 1):

Even if this code were correct, a while loop is hardly the correct approach to initiating a time-based action. While this is also true on the desktop, this is especially so on a mobile phone, since busy waiting in a while loop consumes a lot more battery than using a proper timer. What you want is a simple [CounDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) which will automatically invoke the `onFinish` function when the time is up.